# Session is getting null on Master.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have stored `Session["UserName"] = userName;` in Login page and want to display on Master.apsx in ASP.NET Here is the code I am displaying on Master

```
string FullID = Convert.ToString(Session["UserName"]);
string ID = FullID.Substring(FullID.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
```

It is working perfectly fine on Login getting username in Session but on Master page session is null. can anybody please help me?

Comment: Where do you see null? is FullID showing null?

Comment: there are many reasons that you can lost the session -